# How do you detect swipe left/right of a notification?

Tags: android, notifications, detection, swipe, direction

I'm looking at DeleteIntent to receive a notification view swipe to dismiss.
I don't see that it can return if a user has swiped left or right. Basically,
I want to use a left swipe as a NO, and a right swipe as a YES; 
instead of using the Android 4.1 expanded notification option for additional UIs.

What do you recommend for getting this function?

Comment: see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/41678470/1545993

Answer (score 1):

Check [Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html). 
I believe you have to `setProgress()` to avoid it from being deleted by the user. Check the link, almost down that page you can read it.

Comment: Thanks for the link. THough I am not looking to prevent user from dismissing the notification. I just want to know if the user had swiped left or right to dismiss it. Making a notification ongoing will prevent it from being dismiss.

Comment: sorry, i guess i misunderstood you.

Comment: found any solution? then share with us.